# Ruby - Hackerrank Puzzle - Save the Prisoner

Tags: ruby

I'm having a hard time understanding how to solve this problem without causing memory allocation problems.  I'm pretty sure my logic is sound but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be good enough.  Does anyone have any recommendations for this so I can understand how to write the code more efficiently?

Here's the problem:
Sample Input:
1
5 2 1
Sample Output
2
There are N = 5 prisoners and M = 2 sweets. Distribution starts at ID number S = 1, so prisoner 1 gets the first sweet and prisoner 2 gets the second (last) sweet. Thus, we must warn prisoner  about the poison, so we print 2 on a new line.

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
n = gets.strip.to_i
n.times do 

arr = gets.strip.split(" ").map { |s| s.to_i}
prisoners = arr[0].to_i
sweets = arr[1].to_i
position = arr[2].to_i
    prisoners_array = (1..prisoners).map { |p| p.to_i}
    starting_position = prisoners_array[position - 1]
    end_position = prisoners_array.size

    awesome_array = (starting_position..end_position).map { |p| p.to_i}
    awesomer_array = (prisoners_array[0]...starting_position).map { |p| p.to_i}
    awesomest_array = awesome_array + awesomer_array

warning = 0

    if sweets > prisoners
        sweets = sweets % prisoners
    end
    for i in awesomest_array

    warning += 1
        if warning === sweets
            puts prisoners_array[i - 1] 
        end
end
end
```

Comment: [As I understand](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack35/challenges/save-the-prisoner) there are N prisoners, 1 to N, and M treats, 1 to M. Just for fun, a deadly poison has been added to treat M. The prisoner are arranged in a circle, in numerical order, and the treats are given out in order, starting with prisoner S. So treat 1 is given to prisoner S, treat 2 goes to prisoner S+1. etc.. If M > N-S, prisoner N gets treat N-S and prisoner 1 gets N-S+1. Round and round, this continues until all treats have been given out. Given N, M and S, which prisoner has enjoyed his last treat?

Comment: Thank you Cary for taking the time to look at the problem, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This appears to be](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack35/challenges/save-the-prisoner) the exercise in question.  The key here is managing your use of modulo (which calculates a 0-indexed position) with the problem (which uses 1-indexed positions).

In the example case, we have **5 people (n)** and want to iterate **2 positions (m)** over them starting from **person #1 (s)**.  Person #1 is index position 0 which we calculate by subtracting one from `s`.  We must also subtract one from the distance travelled `t` because getting to the starting position is considered the first move.  So we have `s+m-2`.

By taking this resultant number, modulo `%` the total number of people, we will have calculated the 0-indexed position that we end up at.  We'll need to add one back to this number to convert back to a 1-indexed system.

While it's okay to take a long-form approach to working exercise problems out (such as by populating arrays and actually iterating over them), this problem can also be solved as follows:

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
gets.strip.to_i.times do
    # n - number of prisoners
    # m - number of sweets
    # s - starting id
    n, m, s = gets.split.map &:to_i
    puts ((m+s-2) % n) + 1
end
```

Comment: Thank you Cam.  After spending time on trying to figure this out, I realized I should have been able to add the number of sweets to the position number to somehow find where in the prisoners it would land but I wouldn't have come to this conclusion anytime soon.  Thank you very much for helping me look at this problem from a much simpler angle.

Comment: @CarySwoveland can you please help me understand the use of the modulo operator? Why must we modulo m+s-2 with n?

Comment: @Spindoctor, I haven't forgotten. Just been busy. Will get to this soon.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you very much for the note above. I really appreciate it. I think I have figured it out. Treating the array like a circular queue, gave me the answer and modulo arithmetic as well (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZZOGaGPBpk)


if x < n, x % n  = x
if x == n, x % n = 0

This helps when you reach the nth position in the queue and need to start from the 0th position. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    for(int q=0;q<t;q++)
        {
      long long int n,m,s;
        cin>>n>>m>>s;
        while(s!=m)
           {
            if(s==n)s=0;
             s++;

            }
            cout<<s;
        //exit(0);
        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i am getting timeout with the above code.tell some solution for c++